# How to close outer v-tooltip on inner v-tooltip hover

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-tooltip

I have two tooltips, one is on an outer element, the other on the inner element like this:

[image: Nested Tooltips]

How do I remove the outer tooltip when the inner tooltip is showing?

***[Here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oey2rzgm/)***

The code is pretty standard, but keep in mind, sometimes [v-tooltip](https://github.com/Akryum/v-tooltip#readme) places tooltips like a modal - on the body level, so the tooltips might not actually be nested.

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-tooltip="'Outer Tooltip'">
    Outer Area
    <div v-tooltip="'Inner Tooltip'">
      okokok
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

***Here's what I've tried:***

On the Outer Tooltip I put a class like this:

```
v=tooltip="{content:'Outer Tooltip', classes:['killOnOtherOpen']}"
```

And then on the inner tooltip:

```
v=tooltip="getTextAndDoStuff()"
...
getTextAndDoStuff(){
    $('.killOnOtherOpen').close();
    return "Inner Tooltip";
}
```

But I get an Error:

> Error in render: "TypeError: $(...).close is not a function"

I've tried it like so: `.close;` - like close is not a function - but nothing happens, not even an error.

I'm looking for a more elegant or standard way to do this. Adding a class and a method to each nested tooltip set will take a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fix this issue by using the `stop` modifier when handling the `mouseover`event, and add a boolean property called `isOpen` to show/hode the outer tooltip.

the `stop` modifier will prevent the event propagation

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isOpen: false,
    message: 'Outer Tooltip'

  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 42px;
}

.tooltip {
  display: block !important;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 5px 10px 4px;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 5px;
  border-color: black;
}

.tooltip[x-placement^="top"] {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.tooltip[x-placement^="top"] .tooltip-arrow {
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  border-left-color: transparent !important;
  border-right-color: transparent !important;
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tooltip[x-placement^="bottom"] {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.tooltip[x-placement^="bottom"] .tooltip-arrow {
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: transparent !important;
  border-right-color: transparent !important;
  border-top-color: transparent !important;
  top: -5px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tooltip[x-placement^="right"] {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.tooltip[x-placement^="right"] .tooltip-arrow {
  border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  border-left-color: transparent !important;
  border-top-color: transparent !important;
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
  left: -5px;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.tooltip[x-placement^="left"] {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.tooltip[x-placement^="left"] .tooltip-arrow {
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-top-color: transparent !important;
  border-right-color: transparent !important;
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
  right: -5px;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.tooltip[aria-hidden='true'] {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .15s, visibility .15s;
}

.tooltip[aria-hidden='false'] {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .15s;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/v-tooltip"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-tooltip="{content: message,
    show: isOpen}" class="box" @mouseover.stop="isOpen=true">
    {{ message }}
    <div v-tooltip="'Inner tooltip'" @mouseover.stop="isOpen=false" class="box">
      okokok
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```